# VBA copy auto filtered data into a new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Below is my code, where I am facing an issue. From different workbooks I need to create 3 new sheets in new workbook. In one I have to filter data based on name of sheet from another workbook. I've stucked with copy filtered data to a new workbook. before that all works fine.

```
    Sub Click()
    Dim xRow As Long
    Dim wbnew, wb1, wb2, wb3, wb4 As Workbook
    Dim sht, Data As Worksheet
    Dim sh1, sh2, Filter As String
    Dim Name As String
    Dim rng As Range
```

'openin files to work with

```
    Workbooks.Open filename:="C:\Users\File1.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True
    Workbooks.Open filename:="C:\Users\File2.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True
    Workbooks.Open filename:="C:\Users\File3.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True
    Workbooks.Open filename:="C:\Users\File4.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True

    wb1 = "File1.xlsx"
    wb2 = "File2.xlsx"
    Set wb3 = Workbooks("File3.xlsx")
```

'here I create a temporary file

```
    Set wbnew = Workbooks.Add
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Data"
```

'defining columns I will work with

```
    sh1 = wb3.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i).Value
    sh2 = wb3.ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i).Value
    Name = wb3.ActiveSheet.Range("F" & i).Value
    Filter = wb3.ActiveSheet.Range("C" & i).Value
```

'main goal is to copy data from 3 different files to new workbook. Below starting with copying data

```
    Workbooks(wb1).Worksheets(sh1).Copy _
    Before:=wbnew.Sheets(1)
    Workbooks(wb2).Worksheets(sh2).Copy _
    Before:=wbnew.Sheets(2)
```

'from third file I have to autofilter data for column U in File4.xlsx with criteria from File3.xlsx defined above

```
    Set wb4 = Workbooks("File4.xlsx")
    wb4.Activate
    xRow = wb4.Worksheets("Transactions").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    wb4.Worksheets("Transactions").AutoFilterMode = False

    wb4.Worksheets("Transactions").Range("A:U").AutoFilter Field:=21, Criteria1:=Filter, Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

'try to copy result from autofilter to new workbook to have 3 new sheets, but having an error, also I tried range copy without success

```
    Workbooks(wb4).ActiveSheet.Range("A1:U" & xRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
    Destination:=wbnew.Sheets("Data")

    wb4.Worksheets("Transactions").AutoFilterMode = False
    End Sub
```

I appreciate your advice. Thank you

Comment: Does `Destination:=wbnew.Sheets("Data").Range("A1")` work?

Answer (score 0):

(Written on my phone, there may be typos): Use advanced filter:-

```
Sub Click()
    Dim xRow As Long
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, wb3 As Workbook, wb4 As Workbook, wbNew as workbook
    Dim sht as worksheet, Data As Worksheet
    Dim sh1 as string, sh2 as string, Filter As String
    Dim Name As String
    Dim rng As Range
'openin files to work with

   set wb1 =  Workbooks.Open(filename:="C:\Users\File1.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True)
    set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(filename:="C:\Users\File2.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True)
    set wb3 = Workbooks.Open(filename:="C:\Users\File3.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True)
   set wb4 = Workbooks.Open(filename:="C:\Users\File4.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True_
  set wbNew = workbooks.add()
   dim i as long 'this was missing
   i = 1 'what should this be?

'defining columns I will work with
with wb3.Sheets(1)
    sh1 = .Range("A" & i).Value
    sh2 = .Range("B" & i).Value
    Name = .Range("F" & i).Value
    Filter = .Range("C" & i).Value
end with
wb3.close false
'main goal is to copy data from 3 different files to new workbook. Below starting with copying data

    wb1.Worksheets(sh1).Copy Before:=wbnew.Sheets(1)
    wb1.close false
    wb2.Worksheets(sh2).Copy  before:=wbnew.Sheets(2)
    wb2.close false
'from third file I have to autofilter data for column U in File4.xlsx with criteria from File3.xlsx defined above


   with  wb4.Worksheets("Transactions")
            xRow =.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
          .range("Z1") = .range("U1")  'I assume Z is clear - insert heading
          .range("Z2") = filter        'insert value
           .range("a1:u1").copy wbnew.sheets("Data").range("a1")  'copy headings
          .range("a1:u" & xrow).AdvancedFilter _
          Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
          CriteriaRange:=.range(2z1:z2"), _
          CopyToRange:=wbnew.Sheets("Data").range("A1:u1")

    End With

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a range for your destination:

```
Workbooks(wb4).ActiveSheet.Range("A1:U" & xRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
Destination:=wbnew.Sheets("Data").Range("A1:U" & xRow)
```

Comment: apologies to Mark Fitzgerald...I didn't see your comment until after I posted. If you want to post an answer and get the rep pts, please feel free.